# Work arounds to printing negative zero in tcl

Tags: formatting, tcl, signed

I'm dealing with rewriting a portion of a script to execute in a tcl because of a tool that's only available in tcl. In this code, the user can provide an option (-m for mirrored) to flip values around the y axis. (Basically, all the x values get multiplied by -1.) When printing out the values that resulted from this flipping, I realized that my output had a -0.0000 wherever the original script had 0.0000.

I fixed this issue by not multiplying the x value by -1 if it's equal to zero as bellow:

```
    if {$mirrored eq "t" && $text_x != 0} {
        #in tcl if you multiply 0 by -1 you get -0 we don't want that
        set text_x [expr {$text_x * -1.0}]
    }
```

I am okay with this solution, but it feels a bit weird to include this one case in my if statement. Is there a more concise, elegant or accepted way of doing this? Or any other way at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add zero:

Replicating your stated behaviour:

```
% set x 0
0
% set y [expr {$x * -1.0}]
-0.0
```

and the remedy

```
% set z [expr {$x * -1.0 + 0}]
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a funny one. I don't know the reasons why Tcl does this. One solution is to simply subtract `text_x` from zero

```
if {$mirrored eq "t"} {
       set text_x [expr {0 - $text_x }]
}
```

Some examples:

```
% set text_x 0
0
% set text_x [expr {0 - $text_x }]
0
% set text_x 0.0
0.0
% set text_x [expr {0 - $text_x }]
0.0
% set text_x 1.2
1.2
% set text_x [expr {0 - $text_x }]
-1.2
% set text_x 15
15
% set text_x [expr {0 - $text_x }]
-15
```

Comment: It does it because IEEE floating point arithmetic works that way. Or at least does so on that particular computer. Tcl just makes sure it renders floating point values such that you get back to the original bit pattern when you round-trip through a string.